# Should Xdebug slow down every request?

Tags: php, xdebug

Even if I shut down IDE and remove XDEBUG_SESSION cookie, however, keep Xdebug extension enabled, pages loads twice or more slower than when Xdebug extension disabled. Is it OK? remote_autostart option is disabled.

Comment: Definitely Yes, maybe like 2x slower (my own observations from like 4-5 years back -- tested using PHP 5.5 or 5.6 on Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Xdebug is loaded, it modifies the engine before Xdebug is configured; Those modifications have a detrimental impact on performance regardless of how Xdebug is configured.

Comment: Of course, it's author is currently working hard to make that problem go away ;-)